# Axios Import error when trying to deploy a firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

Hello everyone I have an issue that I did not manage to find the solution to.
I have an index.js file that I use to deploy functions to firebase.
I use Axios for the request. In order to use the Axios package I have to use the world import, but this generates an error.

I tried everything but nothing seems to work in the sense that, if I use const .... instead of import the file gets deployed but the function does not work anymore because it does not find Axios when using const ... , it works just when I use import.

This is the code and below that it is the error:

Code :

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
import { default as axios } from "axios";
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
const page = 1;
const fiat = "RON";
const tradeType = "BUY";
const asset = "USDT";
const payTypes = ["ING"];
let finalData = [];
let tempDataBeforeProccessing = [];

const baseObj = {
  page,
  rows: 20,
  publisherType: null,
  asset,
  tradeType,
  fiat,
  payTypes,
};

const stringData = JSON.stringify(baseObj);

const getTheData = function() {
  tempDataBeforeProccessing=[];
  axios.post("https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search", baseObj, {
    hostname: "p2p.binance.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Length": stringData.length,
    },
  }).then((res)=>{
    tempDataBeforeProccessing=res.data.data;
  });
};


const processData = function() {
  finalData=[];
  let obj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < tempDataBeforeProccessing.length; i++) {
    let payTypesz = "";
    for (let y = 0; y <
    tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length; y++) {
      payTypesz +=
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"][y]["identifier"];
      if (y <
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length - 1) {
        payTypesz += ", ";
      }
    }
    obj = {
      tradeType: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeType"],
      asset: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["asset"],
      fiatUnit: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["fiatUnit"],
      price: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["price"],
      surplusAmount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["surplusAmount"],
      maxSingleTransAmount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
      minSingleTransAmount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["minSingleTransAmount"],
      nickName:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["advertiser"]["nickName"],
      monthOrderCount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["advertiser"]["monthOrderCount"],
      monthFinishRate:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["advertiser"]["monthFinishRate"],
      payTypes: payTypesz,
    };
    finalData.push(obj);
  }

  console.log(finalData);
};

const uploadData = function() {
  database.collection("SebiBinanceSale").doc("BCR Bank").delete();
  for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
    database.collection("SebiBinanceSale").doc("BCR Bank")
        .collection("1").doc(i.toString())
        .set({
          "tradeType": finalData[i]["tradeType"],
          "asset": finalData[i]["asset"],
          "fiatUnit": finalData[i]["fiatUnit"],
          "price": finalData[i]["price"],
          "surplusAmount": finalData[i]["surplusAmount"],
          "maxSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
          "minSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["minSingleTransAmount"],
          "nickName": finalData[i]["nickName"],
          "monthOrderCount": finalData[i]["monthOrderCount"],
          "monthFinishRate": finalData[i]["monthFinishRate"],
          "payTypes": finalData[i]["payTypes"],
        });
  }
  console.log("Succes Upload of the data ");
};

const entireCall = function() {
  getTheData();
  processData();
  uploadData();
};


entireCall();
```

Error :

```
2:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 

'sourceType: module'

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ivanoiualexandrupaul/.npm/_logs/2022-10-29T11_17_45_143Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

If someone manages to give me a hint than you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `import * as axios from "axios";`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck